# How to tell Applescript to group query results?

Tags: fonts, applescript

I'm on OSX 10.11.4. I'd like to get a list to stdout of all installed fonts. Specifically, I'd like the "friendly" name and the file name. Applescript seems the most "native" way to go but I'm new to it - maybe this is a simple question. So far, I have this which almost works:

`osascript -e 'tell application "Font Book" to {name, files} of typefaces'`

That gives me what I want but the names and file names are returned as two concatenated lists. For example:

`Arial, Arial Bold, file Arial.ttf, file ArialBold.ttf ...`

Is there a simple way to have Applescript output something more like:

`{Arial, file Arial.ttf}, {Arial Bold, file ArialBold.ttf} ...`

I don't care if it's precisely that format but I need to be able to parse the output easily and grouping the results into tuples is preferred too.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, consider AS Records:

```
set fontData to {}

tell application "Font Book"
    set fff to every typeface
    repeat with fx in fff
        set end of fontData to {FontFile:fx's files, FontDisplayName:fx's displayed name}
    end repeat
end tell
```

Once you have the records, you can save the list to a file, then parse it multiple ways without having to execute the script over and over again.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I ran this on my MBP and it took 2.5 minutes. My one-liner above takes .3 seconds. Any idea why this is orders of magnitude slower? Are AS Records slow to manipulate?

Comment: They are slow to create.  That is why I suggested that you run it once, get the data you want, save the list to disk, and then do more specific queries and manipulations at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

this bash **oneliner** is handy to get a list of all installed fonts by name or anyother properties (file path, type etc.) formatted for easy parsing/piping:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Font Book"’ \
-e 'set myf to the name of every font family as list’ \
-e "set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed” \
-e 'return myf as string’ \
-e 'end tell’
```

It runs **fast** - but I let everyone be the judge of that : **`time : real 0.273  user 0.067`**
*(time command vs. 396 font library & Apple Terminal - bash5.1 on MacOS11.1)*

Use with anyother font property, i.e **to list your fonts `file path`** instead of their family name : **simply change `font family`** with **`font containers`** in the code.

Nota: all the various fonts properties are defined in Font Book’s applescript dictionary - best accessed with Apple’s trusted and tested (if venerable) **Script Editor** : **`Applications/Utilities/Script Editor >File >Open Dictionary :Font Book`**

> **Steps**:
>
> - the code creates an empty list in applescript: *“myf”*
> - it asks the app *Font Book* to populate that list with the name of every *font families*
> - it converts the list *”myf”* into a *string* where each list item will be delimited by a *“linefeed”* character (e.g. \n)
> - finally it returns the whole string which is now very easy to parse in the shell (with a *”while.. read.. loop..”* as an example)